# Checking deployed programs causes a timeout error. Sometimes works

Tags: solana-program, solana-cli, deploy

I've created a program, and deployed it using:

```
solana program deploy target/deploy/hello_solana.so
```

It deploys successfully:

```
solana program deploy target/deploy/hello_solana.so --keypair ../../sol-wallet/keypair.json
Program Id: 6AYSqby23YGLpQDqoMLgo5Q3VeeY8JagzjtAiG6x9Yph | 274338204 | 9RmrQD5kBthJ9oVrAfryiTJmwDBfmknJDrKGsj71PzVB
```

I attempt to check the programs I have deployed with the following command:

```
solana program show --programs
```

But, I get a timeout error:

```
Error: error sending request for url (https://api.devnet.solana.com/): operation timed out
```

I've tried different machines, and different Internet connections. It still produces the same result.

The strange thing is 1 in 10 times it will work and show my programs. So I don't think this is an issue my end. I've Googled this issue but can't find a resolution.

[image: Sometimes works, other times it timesout]

Anybody know what is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be a rate limit on the public RPC. https://api.devnet.solana.com/

There are many other commercial RPC provider like for example: Triton, Helius, Quicknode, Hellomoon and many more. Most of them also have free plans with less restricting limits.